# Insert Javascript Function Value in Partial View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a javascript function which returns a value that I am trying to display in a table in my partial view.

In my main view I have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(i) 
    {
        var url = '/myurl/?id=' + i;

        $.getJSON(url)
        .done(function (data) 
        {
            return data;
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my partial view html I am trying to do this:

```
<td><script>document.write(myFunc())</script></td>
```

The function gets called but it seems to always return `undefined` am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: try `<td><script>window.myFunc();</script></td>`

Comment: with the semi-colon it doesn't get called at all, without the semi-colon I get the same result "undefined"

Comment: `<script>var data = window.myFunc(); console.log(data); </script></td>`

Comment: same thing, "undefined"

Comment: You should check `window` object in your partial view. Please check `<script>console.log(window); </script>` Please check whether you're getting your function here ?

Comment: I think there is a async issue, I will update my question with a more accurate representation of what I actually have in my code...

Comment: thanks for helping realize what my issue was!

Comment: After watching your code I got to know it was happening because of async call of ajax.

Answer (score 1):

> This is because you are not passing parameter in function and function
>   aspect parameter.. which is null at this stage.

- your call ...

  `document.write(myFunc())`
- and your Function

  `function myFunc(i)`
- so your URl become

  var url = '/myurl/?id=' + Null; // some thing like this

> so URL is not correct and hence not getting correct data

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, once I realized this was an asynchronous issue the solution was obvious and I should have done this in the first place...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(i) 
    {
        var url = '/myurl/?id=' + i;

        $.getJSON(url)
        .done(function (data) 
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = data;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This did the trick.